# Laravel : Store input field value in session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to put my input field into Session, it's a POST request But field which I'm taking as input through form will not store into database. How do I set it to Laravel Session.

```
<input id="moneyReceived" name ="moneyReceived" onchange="payable()" type="text">

{{ Session::put('moneyReceived', $_POST['moneyReceived']) }}
```

Though It's not stored in Session!
Can anyone suggest please?

Comment: share more about how you interact with `moneyReceived` in your controller ?

Comment: actually I don't store `moneyReceived` in controller. It's just javascript dependent input field.based on previous input!

Comment: The session object is only available on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Data from the form is passing to some method. So the method should look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    session(['moneyReceived' => $request->moneyRecieved]);
    ....
}
```

Comment: actually I don't store moneyReceived in controller. It's just javascript dependent input field.based on previous input!